# Scrapy yield a Request, parse in the callback, but use the info in the original function

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

So I'm trying to test some webpages in scrapy, my idea is to yield a Request to the URLS that satisfy the condition, count the number of certain items on the page, and then within the original condition return True/False depending...

Here is some code to show what i mean:

```
def filter_categories:
    if condition:
        test = yield Request(url=link, callback = self.test_page, dont_filter=True)
        return (test, None)

def test_page(self, link):
    ... parse the response...
    return True/False depending
```

I have tried messing around with passing an item in the request, but no matter what the return line get's triggered before test_page is ever called...

So i guess my question becomes is there any way to pass data back to the filter_categories method in a synchronous way so that i can use the result of test_page to return whether or not my test is satisfied?

Any other ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [inline_requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) package, which should let you achieve this.

Other solution is to not insist on returning the result from original method (`filter_categories` in your case), but rather use [request chaining](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments) with `meta` attribute of requests and return the result from the last parse method in the chain (`test_page` in your case).

Comment: quick follow up, im unsure how you use the response variable though? the docs/examples are pretty worthless

Comment: because the response i pass ends up being none

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct: you want to `yield scrapy.Request` to URLS that will have `True` condition. Am I right? Here some example for it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if self.test_page(response):
        item = Item()
        item['url'] = 'xpath or css'
        yield item
    if condition:
        yield Request(url=new_link, callback = self.parse, dont_filter=True)


def test_page(self, link):
    ... parse the response...
    return True/False depending
```

If you give more info I'll try help more.

It's part of my code

```
 def parse(self, response):
        if 'tag' in response.url:
            return self.parse_tag(response)
        if 'company' in response.url:
            return self.parse_company(response)

    def parse_tag(self, response):
        try:
            news_list = response.xpath("..//div[contains(@class, 'block block-thumb ')]")
            company = response.meta['company']
            for i in news_list:
                item = Item()
                item['date'] = i.xpath("./div/div/time/@datetime").extract_first()
                item['title'] = i.xpath("./div/h2/a/text()").extract_first()
                item['description'] = i.xpath("./div/p//text()").extract_first()
                item['url'] = i.xpath("./div/h2/a/@href").extract_first()

                item.update(self.get_common_items(company))

                item['post_id'] = response.meta['post_id']

                if item['title']:
                    yield scrapy.Request(item['url'], callback=self.parse_tags, meta={'item': item})

            has_next = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'river-nav')]//li[contains(@class, 'next')]/a/@href").extract_first()
            if has_next:
                next_url = 'https://example.com' + has_next + '/'
                yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse_tag,
                                     meta=response.meta)

def parse_tags(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['tags'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='accordion recirc-accordion']//ul//li[not(contains(@class, 'active'))]//a/text()").extract()

    yield item
```

Comment: More so that I need to receive information back from the callback of the scrapy request... so in other words. after i yield a request in parse, I need to parse that page in the callback, and depending on what is within i would ideally return true/false or some variable back to the "parse" method where the request was yielded.. which would then allow me to proceed as desired.  So, in other words, i need to yield a Request, parse the info in the callback immediately, and then use that information on the next line after the Request was yielded

Comment: As far as I remember - it not possible. You cannot return any value from callback to `parse` function, only go forward.

Comment: But you can make `yield` in function `test_page`

Comment: I added part of my spider above

Comment: Im not trying to return a value to parse, im trying to return a value from a callback to the method the Request was yielded in. in other words make the Request execute immediately, the code underneath the request wait for the callback to finish, and the callback pass some True/False back to the method which yielded the Request

Answer (score 0):

you can  use:

```
response.meta
response.body
```

**yield from** a function

to refactor your spider